# Suggest me good open source game drawings software

Tags: android

I'm developing a 2D game using andengine, so far I have developed some of the functionality of my game but now I need to implement a good looking 2D sketches and pictures. Can anybody suggest me an open source drawing or designs software for windows? 
Share if anyone has good experience with any drawing app they have used so far.

**Regards,

:Deepak**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depepnding on what you want to achieve and which tools you want to use (like digital pen, mouse, etc.) you can use some of these:

Gimp (http://www.gimp.org/), usefull information http://gimpmagazine.org/

Inkscape (http://inkscape.org/), tutorials http://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/

Blender, (http://www.blender.org/), help and tutorials http://www.blender.org/education-help/

I know, blender is for 3D, but you still can use to make some isometric scenes and create preview videos, because it has everything to create a game (of any type). in place

*If something is wrong, please reply so I'll be able to fix :) thanks.*

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I have explored these apps and looking great. Thanks again for sharing this.